# Reading from a text file and then using the input with in the program

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010

I want to have a program read a text file with 20 single characters, that are on separate lines. I want to then have those characters compared against preprogrammed letters in the program where it will output the wrong ones and the total wrong. I have successfully constructed the program where I can manually enter the letters and it will do as I wanted, but my knowledge of using files within the code is limited. I have read about vectors but I would like to keep it simple first and get the hang of it before I try to learn something else. I have tried to set up a some code that resembles what I think it should probably look like.

I'm not getting any errors now... How do I get the text from the file to the program? I've constructed a somewhat code that almost does it but can't figure out the last steps to connect it. Is it possible for someone to help steer me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance. With the help of this forum I am learning much more than I ever thought was possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void input(char[], int); //Function prototype
void checkAnswers(char[], char[], int, int);

int main()
{

const int NUM_QUESTIONS = 20;
const int MIN_CORRECT = 15;
int correctAnswers = 0;  //Accumulator for number of correct answers
int incorrectAnswers = 0;    //Accumulator for number of incorrect answers
char answers[NUM_QUESTIONS] = { 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C',
'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D',
'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D',
'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A'};

char stu_answers[NUM_QUESTIONS];

ifstream infile;
infile.open("key.txt");

//Check for Error
if (infile.fail()) 
{
    cerr << "Error Opening File" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

string s1;
int count = 0;

// Reads file to the end
while (!infile.eof()) {
    infile >> s1 >> stu_answers[NUM_QUESTIONS]; 
    count++;
}
cout << count << " Students Answers" << endl;


checkAnswers(answers, stu_answers, NUM_QUESTIONS, MIN_CORRECT);
system ("pause");
 return 0;
}

void checkAnswers(char answers1[], char stu_answers1[], int NUM_QUESTIONS, int
MIN_CORRECT)
{
cout << "max: " << NUM_QUESTIONS;
int correctAnswers = 0; 
int incorrectAnswers = 0;
int wrongAnswers[]= {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int j = 0;

//Check the student's replies against the correct answers
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_QUESTIONS; i++)
{
if (answers1[i] == stu_answers1[i])
correctAnswers++;
else if (answers1[i] != stu_answers1[i])
{
incorrectAnswers++;
wrongAnswers[j] = i + 1;
j++;
}
}
//Did they pass or fail?
if (correctAnswers >= MIN_CORRECT)
{
cout << "\nYou must have at least 15 correct to pass.";
cout << "\nStudent passed the exam\n\n";
}
else
{
cout << "\nYou must have at least 15 correct to pass.";
cout <<"\nStudent failed the exam\n\n";
}

//Display a list of the questions that were incorrectly answered.
cout << "The list below shows the question numbers of the incorrectly"; 
cout << " answered questions.\n";
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_QUESTIONS; i++)
{
if (wrongAnswers[i] != 0)
cout << "Question # " << wrongAnswers[i] << " is incorrect." << endl;
}

//Display the number of correct and incorrect answers provided by the student.
cout << "\nCorrect Answers = " << correctAnswers << endl; 
cout << "Incorrect Answers = " << incorrectAnswers << endl;
}
```

The text file is just a notepad .txt file named "key" with the following:

```
C
D
A
A
C
A
D
C
C
D
B
C
D
A
D
C
A
A
D
A
```

Comment: Not that I have to turn in, but it is from the book we are using for class. I'm taking an online course and we will have a problem similar to this as a project next week.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code? If you can't explain what the actual problem is, we can't help you solve it. We're not going to debug your code in order to figure out what you're asking; you have to do that, and then ask a specific question about the problem itself. Hint: You're reading individual lines into individual array elements, so you'll need to read each line individually and put it into the corresponding array element. This will require a loop and counter (like `count` in your existing `while !infile.eof()` loop, where that counter is the array index.)

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the steering of direction I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can directly read in the characters. I've tested the code below. You may have a try.

```
while (!infile.eof() && count < NUM_QUESTIONS) {
    infile >> stu_answers[count++]; 
}
```

`count` is still the number of student answers.

Comment: That was the missing piece I've been searching for. Thank you for taking the time to take a look this and help a struggling newbie.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::getline` function to get one line at a time. It looks like this:

```
std::string strLine;
int nCount = 0;
while (std::getline(infile, strLine))
{
    stu_answers[nCount++] = strLine.at(0);
}
```

Then `nCount` will be the answer number.